# いつもあなたの名前呼んでいるのよ 気付いてよ此処に来て

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, explanatory-の, particle-よ

> いつもあなたの名前呼んでいる**のよ** 気付いて**よ**此処に来て

What is the meaning of のよ in 呼んでいるのよ?
What is the function of よ in 気付いてよ此処に来て?

Does this sentence mean:

> I have been calling your name, (so) please be noted and come here.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

- This の is ["explanatory-no"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010). I hope you already know this の because it appears in many formal sentences. Semantically the sentence is the same as 名前を呼んでいる**の**だ/です.
- This よ after の is a [feminine sentence-end particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12986/5010) (Note that explanatory-の is a kind of noun). It adds a small emphasis (like English "you know", "yeah", etc). The second よ after 気付いて is also a sentence-end particle used to emphasize the request (i.e., "please", "hey"), but this one is gender-neutral.

Practically, this のよ doesn't have to be translated, but you can use something like "you know" to add an emotion to the sentence.

Comment: Your lucid explanation is much  appreciated. I get it now.

Comment: のよ is usually used only by female. んだよ has the same meaning but this is used by both male and female.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation looks perfect to me. If I rewrite it to a more formal one, it will be like "いつもあなたの名前を呼んでいます。だから気づいてください。此処に来てください". So the first のよ can be translated to "so", and the second よ is to "please" as you wrote in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! The sentence is actually lyrics from a song called 名前　by 矢野真紀. I assume the style of the wordings is in more of a spoken/casual form?

Comment: Yes the one you wrote is casual for sure. I'm not sure if it's a spoken form though. I'd say it's a form of lyrics :)