# Does よ in 歩きたいですからよ correct?

Tags: grammar, particle-から, feminine-speech, particle-よ

In a context like this:

A. どうしてドアを開けましたか。

B.歩きたいですからよ。

The bunpo-check keeps showing me that the よ is not correct.
If it's so, why, and if it's correct, does the よ make the sentence sounds feminine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

よ by itself is not wrong, but the part before it is wrong. In this context, you have to say 歩きたい**からです**(よ).

- ～からです = It is because ～.
- ～ですから = because it is ～, ...

よ as a sentence-end particle may or may not sound feminine depending on the type of the word it follows. よ does not sound feminine after です or だ. For details, see: [how could a sentence end with (noun + "よ"?)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12986/5010)

(からよ is a possible combination when よ is used [as a filler particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14924/5010), but this type of よ sounds rough and masculine, and doesn't go well with です/ます.)

Also note that you usually need an explanatory-の in the first sentence: どうしてドアを開けたのですか or どうしてドアを開けたんですか.

Comment: So in the first sentence, using ます form is not usual and natives tend to use the verb with です/だ? Also does よね work  as a filler as well? Thanks!